# Почему аргументом функции нельзя указать двумерный массив?

Tags: c++, массивы, функции

Почему такой код работает:

```
#include "pch.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

void r(int arr1[]) {
}

int main()
{
   setlocale(0, "");
   int a[34] = { 1,4 };
   r(a);
}
```

а такой нет:

```
#include "pch.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

void r(int arr1[][]) {
}

int main()
{
    setlocale(0, "");
    int a[2][2] = {
        {1,1},
        {1,2}
    };
    r(a);
}
```

Ошибка возникает при записи аргумента функции `void r(int arr1[][])`

Comment: В языке С++ в принципе не допускается декларация `int arr1[][]`. К параметрам функций это не имеет никакого отношения.

Comment: `void r(int** arr1) {`?

Comment: @gil9red, двойной указатель и двумерный массив это совершенно несовместимые типы.

Comment: @ixSci, но работать ведь будет?

Comment: @gil9red, нет, ведь это совершенно разные типы. Прочитайте статью, ссылка на которую есть в моём ответе, там я всё это детально разобрал.

Comment: @gil9red: Даже компилироваться не будет.

Answer (score 4):

Ну давайте подумаем... Компилятор обращение к элементу массива (а массив располагается в памяти как единый блок) `a[m][n]` вычисляет как `*(a+m*N+n)`, где `N` - вторая размерность массива.

И откуда же ему знать `N` при компиляции вашей программы? Причем - именно во время компиляции!

Вот если бы вы передали в функцию, например

```
void r(int arr1[][2])
```

тогда дело другое... Вот, запустите [этот код](https://ideone.com/EvbasQ):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
void r(int arr1[][2])
{
    cout << arr1[0][0] << endl;
    cout << arr1[1][1] << endl;
}
int main()
{
    int a[2][2] = {
        {1,1},
        {1,2}
    };
    r(a);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Потому что массив вообще не может быть параметром функции. Эта запись: `void r(int arr1[])` полностью эквивалентна `void r(int* arr1)`, а вторая: `void r(int arr1[][])` вот этому: `void r(int (*arr1)[])`.

Что такое массив указателей неизвестного размера? Неизвестно. Вот поэтому и нельзя. Вы должны явно указать размер массива: `void r(int arr1[][2])`, тогда получится `void r(int (*arr1)[2])`, что является корректным типом.

Подробнее писал об этом в [этой статье](http://scrutator.me/post/2016/03/30/pointers_demystified_p3.aspx).

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, спасибо, поправил!

Answer (score 0):

Внезапно, в аргументах функции вообще нельзя указать массив... В первом случае `int arr1[]` `arr1` будет на самом деле указателем на `int`, а во втором - указателем на массив `int` неопределенной длинны (что запрещено). Как вариант, передавайте массив по ссылке:

```
void r(int ( & arr1 )[2][2])
```

Answer (score 0):

Вот только не надо путать си с паскалем. Здесь многомерных массивов не бывает. И нельзя передать то, чего просто нет. И не надо кивать массивы массивов. Передавайте кратный указатель или заверните оба массива в объекты.